# Efficiently write SPSS data into Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, spss, openpyxl

I am trying to use Python to write data from an open SPSS dataset into an excel file. The below program works fine, but it takes about 35 seconds for a file with 1.4 million data-points (2500 cases, 700 variables).

For now, I am looping through each case (as a tuple), then assigning each element of the tuple into a cell. `openpyxl` is the Excel module of choice (as I did not use any other in the past).

I am going to use the Python program for much larger data-sets, so I was wondering if there is a more efficient logic of doing this.

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.

import spssdata
import spss,spssaux, sys
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
import gc

#initialise timer
time_start = time.time()

#Create the workbook to save the codebook 
wb=openpyxl.Workbook()
ws1=wb.create_sheet()

spss.StartDataStep()
MyFile = spss.Dataset()
varDict = spssaux.VariableDict()
MyCases=MyFile.cases
MyVars=MyFile.varlist

for varnum, varname in enumerate(MyFile.varlist):
        ws1.cell(row=1,column=varnum+1).value=varname.name
        ws2.cell(row=1,column=varnum+1).value=varname.name

for eachcase in range (len(MyCases)):
    for eachvar in range (len(MyCases[eachcase])):
        ValueToWrite=MyCases[eachcase][eachvar]
        ws1.cell(row=eachcase+2,column=eachvar+1).value=ValueToWrite

spss.EndDataStep()

wb.save("some filename")
del wb
gc.collect()
time_end = time.time()
time_taken = int(time_end-time_start)
print ("Saving took " + str(time_taken) + " seconds.")
END PROGRAM.
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are wanting to drive this export using Python? As it looks to me it is a straight forward export of a rectangular dataset into Excel? Why not just use native SPSS to save dataset as Excel? What is the reason for needing this to be driven in Python?

Comment: You are correct, it is basically a straigh-forward export of the dataset. But I am also doing some transformations, formatting, writing parts of data to multiple wroksheetssheets, and everything is already scripted in Python. I plan to make it an SPSS extension. Saving seemed to be the easy part, but turned out to be pretty time consuming.

Comment: I have used/use `xlsxwriter` which has a `set_column` method so avoids the need to loop for each row/case to populate the Excel file. It also has various other features for formatting ect.

Comment: set_column() seems to be for setting column properties, like width, outline elevel, etc - rather formatting than data. Or am I missing the point in the documentation...? I will try with `worksheet.write_row()` method, which might to be doing exactly what I had in mind

Answer (score 1):

You could experiment with using the `win32com` approach. This is normally quite slow, but it does have the advantage of being able to do most of the data transfer in a single call. You would just need to prepare your data into a suitably sized list:

```
import win32com.client as win32

data = [["A", "B"] for _ in range(10000)]

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets.Add()
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(len(data), 2)).Value = data
wb.SaveAs(r'c:\python\test.xlsx')
excel.Application.Quit()
```

Timing this with `range(1000000)` took about 7.5 seconds.

AFAIK there is no way in `openpyxl` to write more than one cell at a time.

---

Based on your existing code, I would suggest something along the lines of:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import time
import spss,spssaux, sys

#initialise timer
time_start = time.time()

spss.StartDataStep()
MyFile = spss.Dataset()
MyCases = MyFile.cases
spss.EndDataStep()

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.DisplayAlerts = False

wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

# Add header to both sheets
ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(1, len(MyFile.varlist))).Value = MyFile.varlist
ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, 1), ws2.Cells(1, len(MyFile.varlist))).Value = MyFile.varlist

# Copy data
ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, 1), ws1.Cells(1 + len(MyCases), len(MyCases[0]))).Value = MyCases

wb.SaveAs(r'e:\python temp\test.xlsx')
excel.Application.Quit()  

print("Saving took {:.1f} seconds.".format(time.time() - time_start))
```

Comment: While this gets things done, it is still very slow. It took about 10% less time on my machine, but it is not the significant efficiency gain that I am looking for when dealing with millions of data points.

Comment: Have you timed `spss.Dataset()` ? I am assuming this part is negligible.

Comment: If I cut out the nested loops in my original code, the rest takes between 2 and 5 seconds (depending on machine resources available)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure lxml is installed and use openpyxl's write-only mode, assuming you can work on a row-by-row basis. If this is not directly possible then you'll need some kind of intermediate structure that can give you rows.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the spss.Cursor class (or spssdata.Spssdata) is much faster than the spss.Dataset class, and for this application you do not need the additional features of the Dataset class.  While the speed of Dataset is mainly an issue when writing to Statistics, the Cursor class will still probably be faster.